# Python - How to run a specific function with variables

Tags: python, function

I'm new to Python. This is the code I am trying to use, basically I am trying to start by adding a hosted zone:

http://ijabour.com/myfaceapp/build/boto/bin/route53

The function for this is: **create**

If I want to add a hosted zone called "test.com", how would I use this library to do this? I want to know how to involve a specific function in this python file and parse an argument to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to call the create function in that module, just import the module and call the create function.

```
import route53
conn = ....  # init connection here
route53.create(conn, "test.com")
```